# EE 3.5 Can't add any custom Member Fields for registration

Tags: ee3, registration, member-management

I'm trying to make it so members have to add First and Last name when registering to use in templates.  I went to Member Fields and tried adding a new one but I always get exception errors.

Exception Caught

No such property: 'm_field_value_label_pairs' on EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Model\Member\MemberField

ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Library/Data/Entity.php:488

Stack Trace: hide details

## 0 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Library/Data/Entity.php(423): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Library\Data\Entity->setRawProperty('m_field_value_l...', false)

## 1 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/Model.php(307): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Library\Data\Entity->setProperty('m_field_value_l...', false)

## 2 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Library/Data/Entity.php(74): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Model->setProperty('m_field_value_l...', false)

## 3 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/Model.php(203): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Library\Data\Entity->__set('m_field_value_l...', false)

## 4 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Model/Member/MemberField.php(159): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Model->__set('m_field_value_l...', false)

## 5 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Controller/Members/Fields.php(393): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Model\Member\MemberField->__set('field_value_lab...', false)

## 6 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Controller/Members/Fields.php(172): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Controller\Members\Fields->form()

## 7 [internal function]: EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Controller\Members\Fields->create()

## 8 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Core/Core.php(189): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)

## 9 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Core/Core.php(94): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Core\Core->runController(Array)

## 10 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Boot/boot.php(151): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Core\Core->run(Object(EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Core\Request))

## 11 admin.php(143): require_once('...')

## 11 admin.php(143): require_once('...')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was apparently a bug in 3.5.0 and this was fixed in 3.5.1 (I upgraded and confirmed it's fixed).